# Keep files near generated files in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a Jekyll blog and some of the raw posts have some additional files at the same level with the markdown file. For example:

`.
├── _posts
    ├── first-post
        ├── 2007-10-29-first-post.md
        └── download.zip`

How can I and up with a generated structure such as

`.
├── _sites
    ├── first-post
        ├── index.html
        └── download.zip`

The *download.zip* file needs to be in the same location as its dependent post (I cannot use any includes or other redirect tricks)

Comment: check https://github.com/nhoizey/jekyll-postfiles

Comment: @AbdulHadi This is great. Please make it and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jekyll-postfiles](https://github.com/nhoizey/jekyll-postfiles) which is:

> A Jekyll plugin that copies static files from the _posts to the _site folder